# Add .chm documentation file of external library to MonoDevelop project?

Tags: c#, monodevelop

I'm trying to use [SFML 1.6](http://www.sfml-dev.org/) in a C# project using [MonoDevelop](http://monodevelop.com/) as the IDE (on Windows 7).  I'm using the Windows download in the "SFML.Net full SDK" section of the [download page](http://www.sfml-dev.org/download.php).  This link lets you download a ZIP archive that, when extracted, results in a directory that contains the file "SFML-1.6\dotnet\doc\SFML.Net.chm".

Is there a way to tell MonoDevelop to use this file to provide class and method documentation in autocompletion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, chm (compiled HTML) files are not a usable form of documentation for the code completion engine. You need the xml version as output by the C# compiler.